# How to convert output time in terms of seconds to minute with UnitConvert[]?

Tags: date-and-time, units

I have this code:

```
AbsoluteTiming[g[x_, t_] := Sin[x]^90*(1 + t^2); 
 Integrate[g[x, \[Tau]], {\[Tau], 0, t}]]
```

with this output:
[image: Convert to Minute]

I want to have convert unit to minute. This is a part of code, I have a formula in iteration. Any suggestion with `UnitConvert[]` ?

Comment: Why not divide by 60, or use `UnitConvert[]`?

Comment: @ J.M. When I use of UnitConvert[] I do not have output for Integral. I have just minute. For example I have problem with this code : `UnitConvert[
 AbsoluteTiming[g[x_, t_] := Sin[x]^90*(1 + t^2); 
  Integrate[g[x, \[Tau]], {\[Tau], 0, t}]], 
 MixedRadix["Minutes", "Seconds"]]`.

Comment: Your use of `MixedRadix[]` confuses me, this is only useful when the duration is more than 1 minute, and you want to convert the output to minutes+seconds.

Comment: @J.M.  `"Minutes"` or `"Minutes, Seconds"` .  If possible for you please consider this code: `UnitConvert[
 AbsoluteTiming[g[x_, t_] := Sin[x]^90*(1 + t^2); 
  Integrate[g[x, \[Tau]], {\[Tau], 0, t}]], "Minutes"]`

Comment: @Karsten I reviewed that question, but I did not use for my code.

Comment: My question is not similar with  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/81268/unitconvert-works-despite-wrong-dimension-bug-or-feature?rq=1 .

Comment: ...then, couldn't you have just used `MapAt[]`?

Comment: Doesn't `hmsAbsTiming2[g[x_, t_] := Sin[x]^90*(1 + t^2);
 Integrate[g[x, \[Tau]], {\[Tau], 0, t}]]` with `hmsAbsTiming2` from [my answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/114578/18476) to the linked question return the desired output?

Comment: @Karsten 7. Dear Karsten I don't have output with `hmsAbsTiming2[g[x_, t_] := Sin[x]^90*(1 + t^2); 
 Integrate[g[x, \[Tau]], {\[Tau], 0, t}]]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I am aware, `AbsoluteTiming[]` gives only answers in seconds, so you need to do this manually

```
MapAt[UnitConvert[# Quantity["Seconds"], "Minutes"] &, 
AbsoluteTiming[g[x_, t_] := Sin[x]^90*(1 + t^2); 
Integrate[g[x, \[Tau]], {\[Tau], 0, t}]], 1]
```

> `{Quantity[0.000146967, "Minutes"], t Sin[x]^90 + 1/3 t^3 Sin[x]^90}`

Comment: Many thanks, but I want to use of `UnitConvert`. Because I have iteration formula and I do not have  output for every frequency.

Comment: Then please amend your question.

Comment: I'd have used `MapAt[]` instead for this: `expr // MapAt[Quantity[#/60, "Minutes"] &, 1]`

Comment: @J.M. Yes, edited to `MapAt[]` which uses `UnitConvert[]` though, as he specified its usage.